# Add CSS to Form Type is Symfony2

Tags: php, css, forms, symfony

I have an edit form, The form is made through symfony2 Form types. I checked the documentation but couldn't find any option for adding CSS to the form. The form display the data correctly and everything is fine what I want to do is to add styling to each field.

My Edit Type is

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
    ->add('id', 'hidden')
    ->add('patent_name', 'text', array('label' => 'Patent Name'))
    ->add('description', 'textarea', array('label' => 'Description', 'required' => false))
    ->add('appln_auth','text', array('label' => 'Application Authorization'))
    ;
}
```

Anyone has any idea ho I can add css ?

Thanks

Comment: It is semantically wrong thing to add presentation stuff (CSS styles, ...) to your FormTypes (logic). So don't do that even if that is possible

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is the way you can do it when building your form,

```
 $builder->add('field_name', 'text', array('label' => 'Field Label', 'attr' => array('class' => 'fieldClass')));
```

You can also do it when rendering your form fields, take a look at [Twig template form function reference](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/twig_reference.html)

```
{{ form_label(form.field, 'label', { 'attr': {'class': 'foo'} }) }}
{{ form_widget(form.field, { 'attr': {'class': 'bar'} }) }}
```

You can then add a css file in your bundle public assets and call it in your template using,

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% parent() %} {# if you want to keep base template's stylesheets #}
    <link href="{{ asset('bundle/myBundle/css/stylesheet.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
{% endblock %}
```

You've then to make your public assets be accessible through your web/ directory.
The best way to do it is to create symbolic links targeting your bundle public assets, you've then to execute

```
assets:install web/ --symlink
```

Another useful approach when you want to thoroughly customize specific form field rendering block (Twig) is to define a new [form theme](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#what-are-form-themes), here's the documentation > [Form theming in Twig](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#form-theming-in-twig).

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
$builder->add('patent_name', 'text', array('label' => 'Patent Name', 'attr' => array('class' => 'someclass')));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add class to your fields, you have to use `attr` special attribute with your build form's `add` action in that way

```
$builder->add('field_name', 'yourType', array('attr' => array('class' => 'fieldClass')));
```

If you want to link your style sheet instead, you have to use assets.

You can find more on assets [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html)

To work with assets you have to do:

- create your css file
- install your assets with `assets:install` (I suggest to use `--symlink` option that will reflect css changes unless they are cached)
- enjoy your CSS by using it into your template. In case of twig, you have do to  <`link href="{{ asset('bundles/acmebundle/css/style.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">` (where `acmebundle` is your bundle)

Answer (score 0):

You can add CSS styling for ChoiceType like this:

```
->add('triage', DocumentType::class, [
                    'label' => 'Triage',
                    'required' => false,
                    'placeholder' => 'select',
                    'label_attr' => [
                        'class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label',
                    ],
                    'choice_attr' => function($choice, $key, $value) {
                        return ['style' => 'background:' . $choice->getColorCode().'; color:white;'];
                    },
                    'class' => 'AppBundle:TriageMaster',
                    'choice_label' => 'triage',
                ])
```

Here I'd used the data from the choice to select the CSS style.